# About notation: line bundles and divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be a Noetherian, regular scheme and let $\mathcal L$ be a line bundle of $X$. Then fix a divisor $D$ on $X$. In some books I've seen the notation $\mathcal L(D)$. What is such an object?

I would say that
$$\mathcal L(D)= \mathcal L\otimes\mathcal O_X(D)$$
is it correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: As Roland said, this is correct, but you should keep in mind when reading Hartshorne's book that sometimes he uses $\mathcal L(D)$ to denote $\mathcal O_X(D)$ in situations where there is no given bundle $\mathcal L$.